# Рекурсивное копирование директорий

Tags: php

Как реализовать скрипт, который копирует директории со всем содержимым?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$sourceDir = 'path/to/source/dir';
$destDir   = 'path/to/dest/dir';

if (!file_exists($destDir)) {
    mkdir($destDir, 0755, true);
}

$dirIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($sourceDir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$iterator    = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    $destPath = $destDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName();
    ($object->isDir()) ? mkdir($destPath) : copy($object, $destPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример функции:

```
function copydirect($source, $dest, $over=false)
{
    if(!is_dir($dest))
        mkdir($dest);
    if($handle = opendir($source))
    {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
            {
                $path = $source . '/' . $file;
                if(is_file($path))
                {
                    if(!is_file($dest . '/' . $file || $over))
                        if(!@copy($path, $dest . '/' . $file))
                        {
                            echo "('.$path.') Ошибка!!! ";
                        }
                }
                elseif(is_dir($path))
                {
                    if(!is_dir($dest . '/' . $file))
                        mkdir($dest . '/' . $file);
                    copydirect($path, $dest . '/' . $file, $over);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
```

Пример: `copydirect("D:\papka1", "D:\papka2", 1);`

Comment: приведите пример использования функции

Comment: $dest что такое?

Comment: @ghost rider, а зачем уже существующие в `dest` файлы не менять?

Comment: поправил код

Comment: copydirect("D:\papka1", "D:\papka2", 1);  ---- копирует всё из D:\papka1  в  D:\papka2 , а надо чтоб сама папка D:\papka1 со своим содержимым копировалась в D:\papka2